# Using php preg_replace to remove some punctuations from utf-8 encoded string

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-replace

I need to remove punctuations except parentheses from  the string. I have come up with following:

```
$clean = preg_replace ( "/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/", "", $maybedirty );
```

That seemed to work OK, until I realized that I need to let through some utf-8 encoded characters (East European). Although I found a number of suggestions of possible solutions, I so far failed to make them work (or to understand them, or both). So question is how can I modify the regex to allow for utf-8 encoded characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$clean = preg_replace('/[^\w\s()]/', '', $maybedirty);
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
[^\w\s()]

Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^\w\s()]»
   A “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, any number, underscore) «\w»
   A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\s»
   A single character from the list “()” «()»
```

Comment: What Pedro Lobito suggested did not work at first attempt. But explanation which accompanied gave me enough pointers what to look for and finally I found the /u (intended for UTF-8 chars. so the final solution look like that:
`$clean = preg_replace('/[^\w\s()]/u', '', $maybedirty);`  This works, except it still passes through the underscore, which should be removed.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you!